Find the determinant of the linear transformation $T(f) = 7f-3f^{'}+7f^{''}$ from the space $V$ spanned by $\cos x$ and $\sin x$ to $V$
Find the determinant of the linear transformation $T(f) = 7f-3f^{'}+7f^{''}$ from the space $V$ spanned by $\cos (x)$ and $\sin (x)$ to $V$.
Ok, so I've gone through the motions of replacing $f$ for  $\sin (x)$ and $\cos (x)$, but that seems to leave me with the matrix. I got the determinant $9$, but that wasn't the correct answer, so I'm at a loss.
This is the matrix: $\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 3 \\ -3 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$
I solved for $7(\cos x)-3(-\sin x)+7(-\cos x) = T(\cos x)$
and $7(\sin x)-3(\cos x)+7(-\sin x) = T(\sin x)$
which then gave me $0\cos x+3\sin x$
and $-3\cos x+0\sin x$
I then transposed it and got $9$, which is the same as if I didn't transpose it, so ik that step isn't what's wrong.
Please help :P

What is the correct answer?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

The specific question is the title exactly as written. The body text is my attempt at solving it.

Who says that nine isn't the correct answer?

The autograder, but if you believe 9 is the correct answer i’ll go ahead and reach out to my professor and ask him to verify my question is right.

Good – that's what professors are for.

Answer was -9 maybe I messed up somewhere

Your answer is right, the determinant is $+9$.
More ‘conceptually’, let $D:V\to V$ be the differentiation operator $D(f)=f’$. The matrix representation of $D$ relative to the basis $\{\sin, \cos\}$ is
\begin{align}
[D]&=
\begin{pmatrix}
0&-1\\
1&0
\end{pmatrix},
\end{align}
which implies $\det D=+1$.
The next thing to note is that on the space $V$, we have $D^2=-I$, because every function in $V$ satisfies the differential equation $f’’=-f$, i.e $f’’+f=0$, because both $\sin$ and $\cos$ solve this linear equation, and $V$ is by definition the span. With this in mind, consider for any $a,b\in\Bbb{R}$ the operator $T_{ab}:V\to V$ given by $T_{ab}(f)=af+bf’+af’’$. Then, we have
\begin{align}
T_{ab}(f):=af+bf’+af’’= a(f+f’’)+ bf’=0+bf’= b\cdot D(f).
\end{align}
Hence, $T_{ab}=b\cdot D$, which implies
\begin{align}
\det(T_{ab})=b^{\dim V}\cdot\det D=b^2\cdot (+1)=b^2,
\end{align}
so in particular the determinant (and in fact the operator itself) doesn’t depend on $a$. Your particular example has $a=7$ and $b=-3$, so the determinant is $(-3)^2=+9$.
